# Problem with vertical lines when adding a background color to a table row

Tags: tables

I have created a table that looks like this:

[image: table 1]

Now, I want to add a background color to the second row. When I do this, however, the second vertical line disappears:

[image: snap 2]

I cannot explain this behaviour. Also, I want a vertical line between the two columns of the first row (Cartesian Coordinates and Reference Points). But it is most important to me that my vertical lines that I already have stay there when adding the background color.

Here is how I have added the table:

```
\begin{table}[t!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{Cartesian Coordinates} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Reference Points} \\
        \hline
        \rowcolor[gray]{.70}
        x & y & z & $\text{RP}_1$ & $\text{RP}_2$ & $\text{RP}_3$ & \dots & $\text{RP}_{80}$\\
        \hline
        $\text{x}_1$ & $\text{y}_1$ & $\text{z}_1$ & $-40$ & $-51$ & $-60$& \dots & $-84$ \\
        $\text{x}_2$ & $\text{y}_2$ & $\text{z}_2$ & $-35$ & $-91$ & $-30$ & \dots & $-55$\\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
        $\text{x}_\text{m}$ & $\text{y}_\text{m}$ & $\text{z}_\text{m}$ & $-20$ & $-320$ & $-41$ & \dots &$-23$ 
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{my Table.}
    \label{myTable}
\end{table}
```

Does anyone see any mistake in this ?

Comment: Do the lines appear if you zoom in?

Comment: it's probably an artefact of your pdf viewer, try zooming in or out and it'll probably appear

Comment: oh ya, you're actually right! ... also: I figured out that the vertical line in the first row appears when I don't use the `\multicol` environment. I kinda need this though

Comment: You can add the line in the first row back in when using {c|} instead of {c} in the multicolumn command.

Comment: you could try the nicematrix package. It draws such color backgrounds with tikz and the lines on top and then such artefacts don't happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `colortbl`, a vertical rule is drawn *before* the colored panel of the adjacent cell on the right (that means that the instructions are in that order in the PDF internal flow).

PDF viewers have problems with such constructions: at low resolution, they usually give priority to the panel which is drawn after and the vertical rule sometimes seems to vanish (rasterisation is a very complex process and that's why the result may not be uniform depending on the number of pixels available).

Even very modern PDF renderers (such as `PDFium` used in `Chromium` and `Chrome` for example) seem to have this behaviour (however `muPDF` used in `SumatraPDF` gives better results).

I have tried to solve that problem in the package `nicematrix`.

In the environment `{NiceTabular}` of this package, you have tools to color rows, columns and cells. The colored panels are drawn before all the rules and the result is better in the PDF viewers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{C|C|C|C|C|C|C|C}[code-before = \rowcolor[gray]{.70}{2}]
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{C|}{Cartesian Coordinates} & \multicolumn{5}{C}{Reference Points} \\
    \hline
    x & y & z & $\text{RP}_1$ & $\text{RP}_2$ & $\text{RP}_3$ & \dots & $\text{RP}_{80}$\\
    \hline
    $\text{x}_1$ & $\text{y}_1$ & $\text{z}_1$ & $-40$ & $-51$ & $-60$& \dots & $-84$ \\
    $\text{x}_2$ & $\text{y}_2$ & $\text{z}_2$ & $-35$ & $-91$ & $-30$ & \dots & $-55$\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
    $\text{x}_\text{m}$ & $\text{y}_\text{m}$ & $\text{z}_\text{m}$ & $-20$ & $-320$ & $-41$ & \dots &$-23$ 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

You need two compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: wow. Did u create this package `nicematrix`?

Comment: Yes. I'm the author of `nicematrix`.

Comment: that's very impressive. Thx so much!

Comment: In this answer, since version 5.0 of `nicematrix` one must write `c` instead of `C` in the preamble of `{NiceTabular}` (but there is an option for backward compatibility).